# How to do find match in json multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find match in multi dimensional json array using jquery. My sample code as follows:
In PHP:

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($is_line);$i++){                                                                  
    if($qty>0){
        $query1[]= $this->db->query("UPDATE ...");
        $query2[] = $this->db->query("INSERT ....");
        $query3[] = $this->db->query("INSERT...");
    }
    else{
        echo "No Modification on the row no:".$i;
    } 
}

$result=array('InIsLine' => $query1, 'stock' => $query2,'IssLine' => $query3);

print_r(json_encode($result));
```

And in js:

```
var result_array=JSON.stringify(result);
```

And the result is:

```
{"InIsLine":[true,true,true,true],"stock":[true,true,true,true],"IssLine":[true,true,true,true]}
```

Here I want to check all the values are true. So anybody guide me.

Comment: Can you share a dummy JSON? Also, if you need help in php, add php tag. That will bring your question to right people.

Comment: You want to search inside a json array? In Php or Jquery? Why is there phpo code? The question is not clear.

Comment: I want to search inside jquery using each.. But i don't know exact method

Answer (score 0):

To check whether an array contains a falsey value, you could use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
// returns true
[true, true, true, true, true].every(function(e) { return e; });
// returns false
[true, true, true, true, false].every(function(e) { return e; });
```

Now to check for a single value, you can use:

```
result_array["InIsLine"].every(function(e) { return e; })
```

Or you can run over all the keys in your object and break as soon as something is falsey:

```
var result_array = {"InIsLine":[true,true,true,true],"stock":[true,true,true,true],"IssLine":[true,true,true,true]};
var allTrue = false;

for(var key in result_array) {
    allTrue = result_array[key].every(function(e) { return e; });
    if (!allTrue) {
        break;
    }
}

console.log(allTrue);
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](https://jsfiddle.net/4ygsnn8k/)

Comment: @mul1103 Have you tried the fiddle/demo? It should work correctly - tested in Safari and Firefox. Do you get any errors?

Comment: In if condition instead of break i worked with alert but that is not working

Comment: @mul1103 Actually it does. [Try it here](https://jsfiddle.net/4ygsnn8k/1/). The fiddle in the answer has all elements set to `true` and will therefor not break the loop. Also the break is only there to avoid unnecessary tests after the first failure. That being said, you should test/alert `allTrue` after the loop.

Comment: allTrue = result_array[key].every(function(e) { return e; });    This line just consider the first value of the array not others... I need to verify all

Comment: @mul1103 I don't know what you mean. It considers every element in each key of the variable `result_array`. If all are true so will be `allTrue`, if there's one single `false`, `allTrue` will be false as well. Maybe you want to test every key by itself, then check them manually as suggested in this line: `result_array["InIsLine"].every(function(e) { return e; })`.

Comment: For me every() is not working .Can u  explain how to do the same thing with php?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Do you get any errors? What browser do you use?Does the fiddle work for you? Is the content in your real situation really something like `[true,true,true,false]` or does your JSON contain a different content? You can also rewrite `every` to a loop and check each value manually.